# phpseclib write empty file

Tags: php, phpseclib

I'm trying to write a CSV and then upload it via SFTP using phpseclib.
This is my code:

```
$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fputcsv($fp, array('url', 'title'), ";");
foreach ($json as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields, ";");
}
rewind($fp);
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('host');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
else {
    $sftp->put("/path/to/file.csv", $fp);
}
fclose($fp);
```

The file is uploaded correctly on my server but it is empty (0 byte). What can I change?
The CSV is correct indeed if I download it from browser (changing PHP header) it has all datas.

Answer (score 1):

I solved adding this inside my `else`:

```
$content = stream_get_contents($fp);
$sftp->put("/path/to/file.csv", $fp);
```